# Cobol - 163 Illegal character in numeric field

Tags: cobol

```
   Identification Division.
   Program-Id. Fifth-Assignment.
   Author. Joanne Lin.
   Date-Written. 04/12/2017.
   Date-Compiled.
  *Joanne Lin.
  *Assignment #5.

   Environment Division.
   Input-Output Section.
   File-Control.

   Select City-File 
       assign to "/home1/c/a/acsi203/cityrates.dat".

       Select Input-File
       assign to "/home1/c/a/acsi203/realestate.dat".

       Select Output-File
       assign to "prog5out.dat"
       Organization is line sequential.

       Select Error-File
       assign to "error5out.dat"
   Organization is line sequential. 


   Data Division.
   File Section.
   FD      City-File.
   01      Input-City.
           02 City-Table            Pic a(15).
       02 Rate-Table            Pic v9(3).
       02 Filler                Pic x.

   FD      Input-File.
   01      Input-Rec.
       02      Street-Address   Pic x(27).
       02      City             Pic a(15).
       02      Zip              Pic 9(5).
       02      State            Pic a(2).
       88 Valid-State        value "CA". 
       02      Bedrooms         Pic 9.
       02      Bathrooms        Pic 9.
       02      Square-Feet      Pic 9(4).
       02      Property-Type    Pic x(8).
       88 Valid-Property values 
                      "Resident",
                      "Condo",
                      "Multi-fa". 
       02      Sale-Day-week    Pic a(3).
       02      Filler           Pic x(1).
       02      Sale-Month       Pic x(3).
       02      Filler           Pic x(1).
   02      Sale-Day         Pic 9(2).
   02      Filler           Pic x(1). 
       02      Sale-Hr          Pic 9(2). 
   02      Filler           Pic x(1).
   02      Sale-Min         Pic 9(2).
   02      Filler           Pic x(1).
       02      Filler           Pic x(1). 
   02      Sale-Sec         Pic 9(2).
   02      Filler           Pic x(1).
   02      Time-Zone        Pic a(3).
   02      Filler           Pic x(1).
       02      Sale-Year        Pic x(4).
       02      Sale-Price       Pic 9(6).
       02      Latitude         Pic 99V9(6).
       02      Longitude        Pic 99V9(7).
       02      Filler           Pic x.

    FD      Output-File
            linage is 58 lines
            with footing at 56
            lines at top 5 
            lines at bottom 5.

    01      Output-Rec              Pic x(132).

FD      Error-File.
01      Error-rec          Pic x(132).


   Working-Storage Section.


    01 Report-Header.
            02 Filler               Pic x(48) value spaces.
            02 Filler               Pic x(43) value
            "California Area Real Estate Transactions - ".
            02 Current-Month        Pic 99.
            02 Filler               Pic x value "/".
            02 Current-Day          Pic 99.
            02 Filler               Pic x value "/".
            02 Current-Year         Pic 9999.
   01 Date-Header.
            02 Year-head            Pic 9999.
            02 Month-head           Pic 99.
            02 Day-head             Pic 99.

   01 Column-Headers.

           02  Filler          pic x(27) value "Address".
           02  Filler          pic x(1)  value spaces.
           02  Filler          pic x(16) value "City".
           02  Filler          pic x(6)  value "Zip".
           02  Filler          pic x(3)  value "St".
           02  Filler          pic x(6)  value "BD".
           02  Filler          pic x(3)  value "BT".
           02  Filler          pic x(4)  value "SFt".
           02  Filler          pic x(10) value "Prop Type".
           02  Filler          pic x(4)  value "Day".
           02  Filler          pic x(4)  value "Mth".
           02  Filler          pic x(3)  value "DD".
           02  Filler          pic x(3)  value "HR".
           02  Filler          pic x(3)  value "MN".
           02  Filler          pic x(3)  value "SC".
           02  Filler          pic x(4)  value "Zon".
           02  Filler          pic x(5)  value "Year".
           02  Filler          pic x(6)  value "Price".
           02  Filler          pic x(6)  value spaces.
           02  Filler          pic x(9)  value "Latitude".
           02  Filler          pic x(10) value "Longitude".
           02  Filler          pic x(7)  value "$/Sq Ft".
           02  Filler          pic x(1)  value spaces.
           02  Filler          pic x(9)  value "Est Value". 

    01 Info-Line.
           02   Street-Address-out     Pic x(27).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   City-out               Pic a(15).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Zip-Out                Pic 9(5).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   State-out              Pic a(2).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Bedrooms-out           Pic x(5).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(2) value spaces.
           02   Bathrooms-out          Pic 9(1).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Square-feet-out        Pic 9(4).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Property-Type-out      Pic x(8).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Sale-Day-week-out      Pic x(3).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Sale-Month-out         Pic x(3).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Sale-day-out           Pic 9(2).
           02   Filler                 Pic x    value spaces.
           02   Sale-hr-out            Pic 9(2).
           02   Filler                 Pic x value spaces.
           02   Sale-min-out           Pic 9(2).
           02   Filler                 Pic x value spaces.
           02   Sale-Sec-out           pic 9(2).
           02   Filler                 Pic x value spaces.
           02   Time-Zone-out          pic x(3).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Sale-Year-out          Pic x(4).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Sale-price-out         Pic $zzz,zz9.99.
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.

           02   Latitude-out           Pic 9(8).
           02   Filler                 Pic x    value spaces.
           02   Longitude-out          Pic 9(9).
           02   Filler                 Pic x(2)  value spaces.
           02   Price-Sq-Ft-Out        Pic $zz9.99.
           02   Filler                 Pic x(1) value spaces.
           02   Estimate-Value-Out     Pic $zzz,zz9.99.




    01 WSMisc-fields. 
           02 WS-Price-Sq-Ft           Pic 9(6)V99.
           02 ws-Estimate-value        Pic 9(6)V99.


           02 Total-Bedrooms       Pic 9(5) value zeros.
           02 Total-Bathrooms      Pic 9(5) value zeros.
           02 Total-Square-Feet    Pic 9(7) value zeros.
           02 Total-Sale-Price     Pic 9(9) value zeros.

           02 Total-Records        Pic 9(5) value zeros.

           02 Avg-Bedrooms         Pic 9(5)V99.
           02 Avg-Bathrooms        Pic 9(5)v99.
           02 Avg-Square-Feet      Pic 9(6)V99.
           02 Avg-Sale-Price       Pic 9(6)V99.

           02 Row-Index            Pic 9(2).
           02 Bedroom-Index        Pic 9.
           02 Sale-Price-Temp      Pic 9(8)v99 value zeros.


   01 Error-out-line.
           02 Filler               Pic x(15) value
                      "Record Number: ".
           02 Error-rec-number     Pic z,zz9.
           02 Filler               Pic x(2)  value spaces.
           02 Error-message        Pic x(30) value spaces.
           02 Filler               Pic xx value spaces.

   01 WS-Error-line                Pic x(114) value spaces.


   01 Averages.
           02 Filler               Pic x(9) value "Averages:".
           02 Filler               Pic x(45) value spaces.
           02 Bedroom-Average      Pic zzz.
           02 Filler               Pic x(2) value spaces.
           02 Bathroom-Average     Pic zzz.
           02 Filler               Pic x(2) value spaces.
           02 SqFt-Average         Pic z,zzz,zz.
           02 Filler               Pic x(5) value spaces.
           02 Sale-Price-Average   Pic $$,$$$,$$9.99.

   01 End-Report.
           02 Filler               Pic x(60) value spaces.
           02 Filler               Pic x(13) value
                           "End of Report".
           02 Filler               Pic x(59) value spaces.

   01 Number-of-files-line.
           02 Filler               Pic x(29) value
                 "Number of records processed:".
           02 Rec-count            Pic 9(4) value 0.
           02 Filler               Pic x(99) value spaces.


   01 eof-flag                        Pic xxx value "No".
   01 Invalid-flag                    Pic xxx value "No".
   01 eop-flag                        Pic x value "N".
   01 eof-city-flag                   Pic x value "N".
   01 match-flag                      Pic x value "N".            

   01 blank-line                  Pic x(132) value spaces.

   01 Page-Footer.
            02 Filler             Pic x(80) value spaces.
            02  Filler                 Pic x value "-".
            02  Page-Num               Pic 9 value 1.
            02  Filler                 Pic x value "-".

   01 Bedrooms-Heading.
            02  Filller      Pic x(18) value "Number of Bedrooms".
            02  Filler       Pic x(6)  value spaces.
            02  Filler       Pic x(22) value
                                     "Accumulated Sale Price".

   01 WS-Num-Bedroom.
            02  Filler   Pic x(5) value "Zero".
            02  Filler   Pic x(5) value "One".
            02  Filelr   Pic x(5) value "Two".
            02  Filler   Pic x(5) value "Three".
            02  Filler   pic x(5) value "Four".
            02  Filler   Pic x(5) value "Five".
            02  Filler   Pic x(5) value "Six".

   01       Ws-Num-Bedroom-Table redefines Ws-Num-Bedroom.
            02 Table-Num-Bedrooms occurs 7 times      Pic x(5).

   01       Ws-Sale-Price-Table occurs 6 times.
            02 Table-bedroom-price     Pic 9(9)v99 value zeroes.

   01       Total-Sale-Bedroom.
            02 Filler                  Pic x(7)  value spaces.
            02 Num-bedrooms            Pic 9(1).
            02 Filler                  Pic x(18) value spaces.
            02 Tot-Sale-Price          Pic $zzz,zzz,zz9.99.

   01       City-Index                Pic 99 value 1. 


   01       City-Rate-Table  occurs 22  times
                   ascending key is city-name
                   indexed by City-Table-Index.
            02 City-Name               Pic a(15).
            02 Multi-Rate              pic v9(3).

   01       Bath-Header.
            02 Filler                  Pic x(13) value spaces.
            02 Filler                  Pic x(5)  value "Baths".
            02 Filler                  Pic x(15) value spaces.
            02 Filler                  Pic x     value "1".
            02 Filler                  Pic x(18) value spaces.
            02 Filler                  Pic x     Value "2".
            02 Filler                  Pic x(18) value spaces.
            02 Filler                  Pic x     Value "3".
            02 Filler                  Pic x(18) Value spaces.
            02 Filler                  Pic x     Value "4".
            02 Filler                  Pic x(18) Value spaces.
            02 Filler                  Pic x     Value "5".

   01       Bedroom-Header.
            02 Filelr                  Pic x(4) value spaces.
            02 Filler                  Pic x(6) value "Bedrms".


   01       Bed-Row     occurs 6 times.
            02 Bath-Col occurs 5 times.
               03 Bed-Bath-Accum      Pic 9(8)v99 value zeroes.

    01      Bed-Bath-Row occurs 6 times.
           02 Filler                   Pic x(15) value spaces.
           02 Bed-Num-Out              Pic zz9.
           02 Filler                   Pic x(8) value spaces.
           02 Bed-Bath-Sale-Out  occurs 5 times.
              03 Bed-Bath-Sale         Pic zzz,zzz,zz9.99.
              03 Filler                Pic x(5) value spaces.
   01      Column-Counter              Pic 99 value 0.




   Procedure Division.

  *Main logic of the program.
   0000-Main-Logic.

            Perform 1000-Init.
            Perform 2000-Main-Loop until Eof-Flag = "Yes".
            Perform 3000-Calculate-Average.
            Perform 4000-Finish.

            Perform 5000-Write-Bedroom-Heading.

  * Prints 1-dimensional table accumulated price
  * per bedroom
            Perform 6000-Print-Tot-Price-Bed
                    varying row-index from 1 by 1
                    until row-index  > 6.
            Perform 8000-Write-Ftr-Space-Line-Num.

            Perform 6500-Write-Bed-Bath-Headings.
            Perform 7000-Print-Bed-Bath-Sales-Tot
                    varying row-index from 1 by 1
                    until row-index > 6.

            Perform 8000-Write-Footer.
            Perform 9000-Close-Files.

            Stop Run.

   1000-init.

            Open Input Input-File
                 Input City-File
                 output Output-File
                 output Error-File.

                 Perform 1500-Load-City-Rate until
                                  Eof-City-Flag = "Y".
                 Close City-File.

                  Move Ws-Num-Bedroom to Ws-Num-Bedroom-Table.

                  Move Function Current-Date to Date-header.
                  Move Year-head  to Current-year.
                  Move Month-head to Current-month.
                  Move Day-head   to Current-day.

               Write Output-Rec from Report-Header
                                  after advancing 2 lines.


                  Write Output-Rec from Column-Headers
                                  after advancing 2 lines.
                  Write output-Rec from blank-line.

                  Read Input-File at end move "Yes" to Eof-Flag.

   1500-Load-City-Rate.

            Read City-File at end move "Y" to Eof-City-Flag.

            If Eof-City-Flag = "N"
               Move City-Table to City-Name(City-Index)
               Move Rate-Table to Multi-Rate(City-Index)
               Add 1 to City-Index.


   2000-Main-Loop.

             Add 1 to Rec-count.
             Perform 2100-Validate-Record.


            If Invalid-Flag = "N"
               Perform 2200-Write-Good-Record
            else
               Perform 2300-Write-Error-Record.

            Read Input-File at end move "Yes" to Eof-Flag.

    2100-Validate-record.

            If Valid-State             and
               Valid-Property          and
               Bedrooms    is Numeric  and
               Bathrooms   is Numeric  and
               Square-feet is Numeric  and
               Sale-Price  is Numeric
               Move "N" to Invalid-Flag
           Else
               Move "Y" to Invalid-Flag.


    2200-Write-Good-Record.

             Move   Street-Address to Street-Address-out.
             Move   City           to City-out.
             Move   State          to State-out.
             Move   Zip            to Zip-out.

             Move 1 to City-Index.
             Move "Y" to Match-Flag.
             Search all City-Rate-Table
                   at end
                       Move "N" to Match-Flag
                    When City-Name(City-Table-Index) = City
                        Compute  Sale-Price-Temp = Sale-Price *
                                      Multi-Rate(City-Table-Index).


             If bedrooms > 0 and Bathrooms > 0 and
                Match-Flag = "Y"
                Add Sale-Price-Temp to
                          Bed-Bath-Accum(Bedrooms,Bathrooms).
             If bedrooms > 0
                Add Sale-Price-temp to Table-Bedroom-Price(bedrooms).

             Compute bedroom-index = Bedrooms + 1.
             Move   Table-Num-Bedrooms(bedroom-index) to
              Bedrooms-Out.


             Move   Bathrooms      to Bathrooms-out.
             Move   Square-feet    to Square-feet-out.
             Move   Property-Type  to Property-Type-out.
             Move   Sale-Day-week  to Sale-Day-week-out.
             Move   Sale-Month     to Sale-Month-out.
             Move   Sale-day       to Sale-day-out.
             Move   Sale-hr        to Sale-hr-out.
             Move   Sale-min       to Sale-min-out.
             Move   Sale-sec       to Sale-sec-out.
             Move   Sale-Year      to Sale-Year-out.
             Move   Sale-price-Temp  to Sale-price-out.


             Perform 2050-Calculation.

            Write Output-Rec from Info-Line at eop
                        perform 2040-Write-Page-Footer.
            Add 1  to Rec-Count.

   2040-Write-Page-Footer.

            Write Output-Rec from Page-Footer
                           after advancing 2 lines.
            Add 1 to Page-Num.

            Write Output-Rec from Report-Header
                          after advancing page.

            Write Output-Rec from Column-Headers
                             after advancing 2 lines.
            Write Output-Rec from Blank-Line.

    2050-Calculation.

             If Square-feet > 0
                Compute WS-Price-Sq-Ft =
                                  Sale-price-temp / Square-feet
             Else
                Move 0  to WS-Price-Sq-Ft.
             Move WS-Price-Sq-Ft to Price-Sq-Ft-out.

             If City = "SACRAMENTO" or "RIO LINDA"
                Compute WS-Estimate-Value = Sale-price-temp * 1.18
             Else
               Compute WS-Estimate-Value = Sale-price-temp * 1.13.
             Move WS-Estimate-Value to Estimate-Value-out.

             If Square-feet > 0
                Add Bedrooms         to Total-Bedrooms
                Add Bathrooms        to Total-Bathrooms
                Add Square-feet      to Total-Square-Feet
                Add Sale-Price-temp  to Total-Sale-Price
                Add 1                to Total-Records.

   2300-Write-Error-Record.

           Move  Input-Rec  to WS-Error-Line.
           Write Error-Rec  from WS-Error-Line.
           Move Rec-count   to   Error-rec-number.

           If not Valid-State
              Move "State is invalid"  to error-message
              Write error-rec from Error-out-line.

           If not Valid-Property
              Move "Propery Type is invalid"  to error-message
              Write error-rec from Error-out-line.

           If Bedrooms is not numeric
              Move "Bedrooms is not numeric"  to error-message
              Write error-rec from Error-out-line.
           If Bathrooms is not numeric
              Move "Bathrooms is not numeric"  to error-message
              Write error-rec from Error-out-line.

           If Square-Feet is not numeric
              Move "Square feet is not numeric"  to error-message
              Write error-rec from Error-out-line.

           If Sale-Price is not numeric
              Move "Sale Price is not numeric"  to error-message
              Write error-rec from Error-out-line.

           Write error-rec from blank-Line.



   3000-Calculate-Average.

           Compute Avg-Bedrooms    =
                    Total-Bedrooms    / Total-Records.
           Compute Avg-Bathrooms   =
                    Total-Bathrooms   / Total-Records.
           Compute Avg-Square-Feet =
                    Total-Square-Feet / Total-Records.
           Compute Avg-Sale-Price  =
                    Total-Sale-Price  / Total-Records.


            Move Avg-Bedrooms    to  Bedroom-Average.
            Move Avg-Bathrooms   to  Bathroom-Average.
            Move Avg-Square-Feet to  SqFt-Average.
            Move Avg-Sale-Price  to  Sale-Price-Average.

   6000-Print-Tot-Price-Bed.

            Move Table-Bedroom-Price(row-index) to
                                        Tot-Sale-Price.
            move row-index  to Num-Bedrooms.
            Write  Output-Rec from Total-Sale-Bedroom.


   4000-Finish.

            Write Output-Rec from Averages
                      after advancing 2 lines.

            Write Output-Rec from Number-of-files-line
                      after advancing 2 lines.
            Perform 5500-Write-Blank-Lines until Eop-Flag = "Y".

   5500-Write-Blank-Lines.

            Write Output-Rec from blank-Line
                    at  eop Write Output-Rec from Page-Footer
                    Move "Y" to Eop-Flag.

   5000-Write-Bedroom-Heading.

            Add 1 to Page-Num.
          Write Output-Rec from Bedrooms-Heading
                               after advancing page.

            Write Output-Rec from blank-Line.

   6500-Write-Bed-Bath-Headings.

            Add 1 to Page-Num.
            Write Output-Rec from Bath-Header
                               after advancing page.
            Write Output-Rec from Bedroom-Header.
            Write Output-Rec from blank-Line.

   7000-Print-Bed-Bath-Sales-Tot.

            Move Row-Index to Bed-Num-Out(Row-Index).
            Perform 7500-Print-Line varying
                   Column-Counter from 1 by 1
                   Until Column-Counter > 5.
            Write Output-Rec from Bed-Bath-Row(Row-Index).
    7500-Print-Line.

            Move Bed-Bath-Accum(Row-Index,Column-Counter) to
                 Bed-Bath-Sale(Row-Index,Column-Counter).


   8000-Write-Ftr-Space-Line-Num.
            Move "N" to Eop-Flag.
            Perform 5500-Write-Blank-Lines until Eop-Flag = "Y".

   8000-Write-Footer.

            Write Output-Rec from blank-line.
            Write Output-Rec from End-Report.

            Perform 8000-Write-Ftr-Space-Line-Num.

   9000-Close-Files.
            Close Output-File Input-File Error-File.
```

How would I go about fixing this error message received with this code:

Error message:

Execution error : file 'prog2.int'
error code: 163, pc=5AB, call=1, seg=0
163     Illegal character in numeric field

Is there anyway to find exactly where the illegal character is in the numeric field? I'm having trouble attempting to find the culprit of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are running some variant of Micro Focus COBOL. You have encountered a run-time error which says "either the source-data is busted (somewhere) or something I've done is busted, and non-numeric data is a in a numeric field".

For this purpose, a numeric field is a `USAGE DISPLAY` numeric or numeric-edited field, or a packed-decimal field (although you don't have any of those, and I'm not completely sure that'll get you a 163).

Both `USAGE` and `DISPLAY` (in the context of USAGE) are optional words which you won't often see. So, an example:

```
           02   Zip-Out                Pic 9(5).
```

If you happen to use Zip-Out for something, then your program will burn if it contains anything other than numbers.

First Tip: just because something is a "number", don't make it numeric unless your processing requires it. Account-number, customer-number, part-number, zip-code can all be simple PIC X fields. You are (almost) never going to use those for calculations or use them as subscripts, so why make them numeric for no purpose? Other examples are days, months, years, hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

Second Tip: become aware of compile options/directives. The 163 can be "turned off" (the test for numeric is made before each reference, which is not so efficient) and there will be other things which can modify the processing. What you probably want here is "show me the line-number it failed at", which I suspect is possible. Read up on the options/directives for your actual compiler.

Third Tip: in the PROCEDURE DIVISION use only the minimum full-stops/periods. At the moment, for instance, all your IF statements are terminated by full-stops/periods. Delete those, and replace by END-IF. Find out what other scope-terminators you should be using in your program, and replace those. Then remove all full-stops/periods except that terminating the PROCEDURE DIVISION header and the labels (paragraph-names). Then, on a separate line, stating in column 12, terminate each paragraph with a single full-stop/period.

An example. You have:

```
   1500-Load-City-Rate.

            Read City-File at end move "Y" to Eof-City-Flag.

            If Eof-City-Flag = "N"
               Move City-Table to City-Name(City-Index)
               Move Rate-Table to Multi-Rate(City-Index)
               Add 1 to City-Index.
```

You could have:

```
   1500-Load-City-Rate.

       Read City-File 
         at end 
           move "Y"                 to Eof-City-Flag
       End-read

       If Eof-City-Flag = "N"
           Move City-Table          to City-Name 
                                        ( City-Index )
           Move Rate-Table          to Multi-Rate 
                                        ( City-Index )
           Add 1                    to City-Index
       End-if
       .
```

Fourth Tip: Don't use "index" in a data-name unless it is an index (defined by `INDEXED BY` on an OCCURS). If it is simply a numeric field which you are using as a subscript, don't name it with "index". The purpose of data-names is to document, accurately, fields. That does not include misleading.

Fifth Tip: If you are required to "number" paragraphs/SECTIONS, I'd suggest desing/write/test the program first, and when it is complete, do the numbering. There is no point in numbers if they are not in sequence, and yours are not. There is no point in renumbering more than once just because you had to fix-up some things due to shortcomings with the design.

Fifth Tip: For data-definitions, leave "gaps" in the level-numbers. You will be hated by the next person along if the have to restructure your data just because there is no "gap" to put in a higher-level definition. It is common to leave gaps of five or so (01, 05, 10, 15...). There is no real downside in doing this and it will preserve your name amongst others who look at your program in the future (which will presumably include your marker).

Sixth Tip: Use 88s. You are using 88s, but you still have literals in the PROCEDURE DIVISION, so you don't really understand the benefits. You are also setting "flags" with `MOVE`. If you use 88s, you can `SET` an 88 to `TRUE`, much clearer than a MOVE.

Seventh Tip: Look around at COBOL questions here from the last four years.  You'll even see examples of the same course work :-) You'll get more Tips from that process.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can take to determine the cause of the "Illegal character" error:

- Analyze the program dump.
- Use an interactive debugger.
- Add code to your program to validate the contents of numeric fields.

---

### Analyzing the program dump

If the error caused your system to produce a program dump, check the dump to see if it provides any useful information.

Dumps will normally provide information such as:

- Which line of your program was being executed when the error occurred
- Which record was last read from each input file
- Contents of program variables

However, if you are not lucky enough to have a dump containing COBOL-specific details, then instead of a line number in your COBOL program, you will get only the address of the next **assembly language** instruction to be executed.

And, instead of the contents of your COBOL program variables, you may get only a **storage dump** of the Working-Storage Section.

You would then need to use a COBOL compiler listing that displays the generated assembly language code in order to map the assembly language instruction to the corresponding COBOL statement, and to map any COBOL variables of interest to the corresponding addresses in storage.  Doing this would likely be difficult and time-consuming for an inexperienced developer.

---

### Using an interactive debugger

If your development environment includes an interactive debugger, you can execute your program within the debugger until the error occurs, and then note the program statement and data that caused the error.

---

### Adding validation code to your program

By adding code to your program to validate the contents of numeric fields before using them, you can not only identify the cause of the error, but also recover from it.

Validations you might want to consider adding include:

(1) Testing the following additional `Input-Rec` fields for numeric content in `2100-Validate-record`:

```
Zip
Sale-Day
Sale-Hr
Sale-Min
Sale-Sec
Latitude
Longitude
```

(2) Testing field `Rate-Table` for numeric content before moving it to `Multi-Rate(City-Index)`.

(3) Verify that the value of `Bedrooms` is <= 6 before updating `Bed-Bath-Accum(Bedrooms,Bathrooms)`, `Table-Bedroom-Price(bedrooms)`, and `Table-Num-Bedrooms(bedroom-index)`, since a value greater than 6 would result in the array indexes being out-of-range.

(4) Verify that the value of `Bathrooms` is <= 5 before updating `Bed-Bath-Accum(Bedrooms,Bathrooms)`, for the same reason as above.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to find exactly where the illegal character is in the
>   numeric field?

Use Micro Focus® Animator®. Select 'Z' for 'zoom' (or whatever menu selection is available to 'zoom'). When the error occurs Animator will stop and highlight the statement with the error. This type of error generally happens when the data item is used as a sending field in an arithmetic statement. For example,

```
   program-id. err-163.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 163-data pic 9(5).
   procedure division.
       add 1 to 163-data
       stop run
       .
```

The line, `add 1 to 163-data`, is highlighted with the error `Illegal character in numeric field  (Error 163)` also shown.

In this case, the program is attempting to add 1 to spaces, because the default for uninitialized data is spaces. The field `163-data` is both a sending and receiving field (in COBOL standard terms). It sends its value, spaces, to the `ADD statement`, this is detected as an error, and the error is either processed or ignored, depending on compiler options.

With any conforming 2002 implementation, a suitable `TURN` directive for `EC-DATA-INCOMPATIBLE` and the intrinsic function `EXCEPTION-LOCATION` could provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

go to command prompt and type this command
set cobsw=-f and press enter and try again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).